# Issue with retrieving Magento Frontend Session

Tags: api, session, magento, amf

I am trying to retrieve the customer's login status from Flex application using AMF call to the Magento Customer API :

```
Mage::app('default');
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend') );
    $sessId= $session->getSessionId();
    if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $name = "Hi ". Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName();
        return 'true' . $name;
    } 
    else{
        return 'false ' . $sessId;
    }
```

Only the PHP session ID is returned:
PHPSESSID=i5s1gcemc6r8uquadc4rsk9ou5

But the user is logged into the below ID
frontend=3qdcimcdp7nq4bi8jlovqmnq61

Let me know if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the customer ID

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend')); 
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session',array('name' => 'frontend'));
echo $customerId = $customer->getCustomer()->getId();
```